# NTP on main server, and alternative on virtual (LXC)

Tags: scripting, ntp, lxc

I am setting up a server with several VPS. I am using LXC.
I am thinking it would be better to have only the main server equipped with ntp and have the virtual boxes just get the time from the main box.
Is there a bash/python/php etc script I could use to get the time from the main server?

Comment: Here is an idea. Set on the main server the hwclock, and have the VPSs pick that up. How does that sound?

Comment: Doing a bit more research. It seams I can run the /etc/init.d/hwclock.sh once in a while to set all clocks. when run with start it set the hardware clock, so this would be done on the main server where I have ntp running and the vps'es could run it with stop to set the system clock, again with a cron job every now and then. How does that sound?

Answer (score 1):

Got no answer, so here is what I did, and I am wondering if there are any consequences to this that I should be aware of.

Main server cron job

```
* 0 *  * * /sbin/hwclock -w
```

Each VPS has following cron job

```
10 0 *  * * /sbin/hwclock -s
```

Thanks